# How to properly compress window 7 excepted bootmgr?

Tags: windows-7

Many answers explain how to start and repair windows 7 when bootmgr is compressed.

My question is: how to compressed windows 7 excepted bootmgr and other files ?

Comment: Compression should not be used for Windows system files and other program files. It will stop Windows Update working. Otherwise select the folder to compress > right click > properties > advanced > enable compress contents.

Comment: OK but this method compresses also bootmgr ! that's why I am looking for a clean method.

Comment: No it doesn't. I didn't say right click on ``c:\``. You **choose** which folders to compress, for example, `c:\mycompressedfolder` is what you right click on. You compress individual folders (of your choice) **not** the whole drive. You cannot say compress "everything but...". Do **not** compress `c:\windows`, `c:\program files` or any other operating system directories.

Comment: what about the "compact" command ? i.e: compact /U c: \bootmgr

Comment: What about it? It is just the command line version of what I said in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Surely not a best practice to compress a Windows OS folder. There are many reasons as to why you should not, the main ones are:

1. Performance. The OS is the base for which everything depends on. Compressing the OS folder will require the OS to uncompress and compress constantly for reads/writes to that folder. As an OS, this will happen all the time while you use the system. For example, you will definitely notice a performance hit in IE as it uses disk caching somewhere under the OS folder, when you compress it IE will become sluggish.
2. Recovery is complicated. If you ever have to recover a failing OS, it will be challenging even without disk compression. Putting compression on the OS folder will make it that much more difficult to recover a failing OS.
3. Antivirus scanning will be slower.

...and I can go on, but I think these three reasons should be enough not to go down the path of compressing the Windows OS folder.